# Performing 3D mapping with Primesense sensor in Python with openNI

Tags: python, openni, primesense

I recently purchased a Primesense sensor 1.09 and I would like to perform 3D mapping for robot vision in Python. Python bindings are avaliable for openNI but I seem to be unable to find any examples or even documentation using python with the Primesense bindings. The only code I've found is here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/primesense. I've seen lots about the C++ API but I'm not sure how to map the C commands to python.

I am looking for sample code in python or a python reference.